# C++ Use Class as Variable

Tags: c++, class, variables, operator-overloading, operators

So I have a class similar to this one:

```
class CVal {
public:
    void operator=(int n) {
        d = n;
    }
private:
    int d;
};
```

Now whenever I do something like

```
CVal c;
switch(c) {...}
```

I want the CVal::d to be accessed, so how would I do that? I thought of overloading some operator but I can't find anything.

Comment: either make `d` public, or make a getter function that returns it, and then do `c.d` or `c.d()` in the switch.

Comment: That is a bad idea. If you have a bug, it will be huge pain in the neck to find it. A better approach would be : `switch(c.GetMyValue()) {...}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should define conversion operator like this

```
class CVal {
public:
    //...
    operator int() const { return d; }
private:
    int d;
};
```

Or if you have a compiler that supports C++ 2014 then you can define it the following way

```
class CVal {
public:
    //...
    operator auto() const { return d; }
private:
    int d;
};
```

According to the C++ Standard (6.4.2 The switch statement)

> 2 The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class
>   type. If of class type, the condition is contextually implicitly
>   converted (Clause 4) to an integral or enumeration type. Integral
>   promotions are performed....

Comment: Reason: The expression in the switch statement must be an integral type. `CVal` is not an integral type, but if an implicit conversion is available, the compiler will use it.

Comment: should conversion operator be `explicit`?

Comment: @Slava making the conversion operator `explicit` would break the code as it is relying on a implicit conversion.

Comment: @Slava When it is defined as explicit then neither clang nor gcc compiles the code.:)

Comment: Fair enough. Another reason not to use such paradigm.

Comment: @Slava  It is an interesting question why it shall be contextually implicitly converted instead of  contextually converted.

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** access a private member of a class. But if you want use the value of a private member no matter what, you need to write **get** functions. eg:

```
class CVal {
public:
    void operator=(int n) {
        d = n;
    }
    int getD() {  // this function returns the value of private member d
        return d;
    }        
private:
    int d;
};
```

Now you can access d in the following way:

```
CVal c;
switch(c.getD()) {...}
```

This option is better than implicity convert the class to make it accessible in **switch**. Because it can save you from possible debugging error in future. Besides many coding conventions prefer this option better.

Comment: He did not ask how to access `d`, he asked how to use instance of the class in `switch()` as it is.

Comment: @Slava true, but this is probably a better option.

Comment: Why did you make `d` static?

Comment: @TartanLlama probably so, but the answer does not say that, this is just an answer to another question  - "how to access d?". Obviously author did not ask that.

Comment: The author asked at the bottom *"I want the CVal::d to be accessed, so how would I do that?"*

Comment: @SudiptoChandra the op wants `c` in `CVal c; switch(c) {...}` to resolve to `CVal::d `

Comment: @SudiptoChandrahe he said that he wants `CVal::d` to be accessed when instance used inside `switch()`, he did not ask how to access `CVal::d` in general.

Comment: I thought of providing another way to his problem.

Comment: @SudiptoChandra then you should explain why this is a better option than an implicit conversion.

Comment: You are right and I just edited my answer to be more speciific.